# Redux Hooks ReactJS - Tentando criar uma estrutura

Tags: javascript, react, redux, react-hooks

estou tentando criar uma estrutura de login usando o Redux e Hooks no React.js. Porém estou tendo um erro que não estou conseguindo entender o motivo. Quem manja bem de Javascript poderá me ajudar.

O guia de referencia é:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/02/react-hooks-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

A unica diferença é que estou usando TS.

Tenho um componente de Login.tsx onde estou pegando corretamente os campos de email e senha.

Depois tenho uma função:

```
function handleLogin() {
    setLoading(true)
    dispatch(userActions.login(email, password))
    setLoading(false)
}
```

Este dispatch chama a função abaixo do userActions:

```js
function login(email: string, password: string) {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        try {
            const user = userService.login(email, password)
            dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGIN", user })
            history.push("/")
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Que chama a função login do userService:

```js
export const userService = {
    login: Function,
    logout: Function,
}

function login(email: string, password: string) {
    return firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user))
            return user
        })
}
```

Realmente não entendo muito bem de Redux e nem sei se é uma boa pratica deixar a estrutura assim:

- `userAction` é responsável por gravar as informações no localStorage e no Redux
- `userService` é responsável por fazer o login no Firebase.

Mas assim que chamo a função na pagina principal, levo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que será que pode ser?

Comment: tenta remover o "@" do e-mail que você está tentando salvar,para ver se funciona,pode ser um erro de reconhecimento de string.

Comment: Esse erro provavelmente deve estar vindo do `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. Tem como [edit] a resposta adicionando o _stacktrace_ do erro?

Comment: @Jeferson só uma observação sobre o seu código, o dispatch() é um método síncrono, logo, assim que você chama o seu dispatch(), antes de terminar sua requisição, o loading é setado para false, portanto acredito que você está tendo um false loading da sua requisição.